# Swap space on a new disk Xubuntu 20.04

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, xubuntu, disk

During the installation of Xubuntu 20.04 on a 256GB SSD I forgot to set up the partitions manually. Now, checking in "Disks" I found a new disk of 1GB used as swap. Why did that happen? How do I delete it restoring the space? I already set up another swap partition.

Edit: here the output of some commands. Keep in mind that I have Full Disk Encryption, I set up a swap file and disabled the 1GB disk.

cat /etc/fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/vgxubuntu-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=901a5584-7d29-4b6c-92c8-3894bbc34c5b /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=CCFB-71F6  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0
c/fstab
```

sudo fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sda: 238.49 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: SAMSUNG SSD PM85
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: E126C68F-FDA4-41B2-B15E-F75A9AE91E09

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624   2549759   1499136   732M Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  2549760 500117503 497567744 237.3G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/mapper/sda3_crypt: 237.25 GiB, 254737907712 bytes, 497534976 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/vgxubuntu-root: 236.26 GiB, 253675700224 bytes, 495460352 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/vgxubuntu-swap_1: 976 MiB, 1023410176 bytes, 1998848 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

sudo blkid

```
/dev/mapper/sda3_crypt: UUID="AyFbsG-1JiR-Vp6a-EuYs-ZdhM-yNbf-ay9h0v" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/mapper/vgxubuntu-root: UUID="66476a50-609f-437e-b952-4d3fde5fa540" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda1: UUID="CCFB-71F6" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="3813ee18-8094-418b-b6da-87839efd404a"
/dev/sda2: UUID="901a5584-7d29-4b6c-92c8-3894bbc34c5b" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="e6a91c90-4d7a-41cd-a720-8b7dabc61382"
/dev/sda3: UUID="eef13d5f-5b90-46c1-8344-e06203822428" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="bc76f04e-616c-46a8-a6a5-347adc7f98f1"
/dev/mapper/vgxubuntu-swap_1: UUID="1cc36555-97cb-4c40-aebd-807ac3f8b687" TYPE="swap"
```

Comment: The simplest way would be to boot into a live session with your Xubuntu install media, then use a partition editor to delete the small swap partition and extend your main one.

Comment: In the encrypted volume hosted on partition sda3, there is indeed your root partition /dev/mapper/vgxubuntu-root and a swap partition /dev/mapper/vgxubuntu-swap_1 that currently does not seem to be used. There is a /swapfile active. I have no experience with encrypted volumes myself.

Comment: It may be a bug in the GUI tool that displays the partition as a separated disk.